# jQuery, HTML5 web design error

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

I have a single page web design in which the menu is vertically aligned and fixed at the left and contents in each page popup at the right when clicked on Menu. It is in a way that when the index page is opened, only the menu is shown without any active menu.

[image]

But I want the home menu to be active and the homepage should be shown at the right time when the index page is loaded.

[image]

The home should be active and loaded automatically in the index.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li><a id="link" href="#!/page_Home"><span></span><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/page_About"><span></span><strong>About</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/page_Portfolio"><span></span><strong>Gallery</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/page_Services"><span></span><strong>Top Rated</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#!/page_Contact"><span></span><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    var act='';

    $('#content > ul > li').css({position:'absolute', display:'none'});
    $('#content > ul > li').find('.box1').css({height:'0'})

    $('#menu > li > a span').css({opacity:'0'})

    $('#menu > li > a').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'1'},600);                         
    }, function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);                         
        }
    })

    $('#menu > li').each(function(num){
        $(this).data({num:num})
    })
    $('#content > ul > li').each(function(num){
        $(this).data({num:num})
    })

    if (location.hash.slice(0,3)=='#!/') {
        page=location.hash.slice(3);
        open_page('#'+page);
        fl=false;
    }
    if ((location.hash=='#')||(location.hash=='')) {
        open_page('');
        fl=true;
            $('#content').stop().animate({height:'668'})
    }
    $('a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('href').slice(0,3)=='#!/') {
            page=$(this).attr('href').slice(3); 
            open_page('#'+page);
            return false;
        }
        if ($(this).attr('data-type')=='close') {
            close_page()    
        }
    })
    function open_page(page){
        location.hash='#!/'+page.slice(1);
        $('#menu a').removeClass('active').find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);
        Cufon.replace('#menu a', { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', hover:true });
        num=$(page).data('num');
        $('#menu > li').each(function(){                      
            if ($(this).data('num')==num) {
                $(this).find('> a').addClass('active').find('> span').stop().animate({opacity:'1'},600);
                Cufon.replace('#menu a', { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', hover:true });
            }
        })
        fl=false;
        $('#content').stop().animate({height:'868'})
        if (act!='') {
            $(act).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'0'},700,'easeOutCirc', function(){
                $(act).css({display:'none'});
                $(page).css({display:'block'}).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'100%'},700, 'easeOutCirc', function(){
                    act=page;   
                }); 
            })
        } else {
            $(page).css({display:'block'}).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'100%'},700, 'easeOutCirc', function(){
                act=page;   
            });     
        }
    }
    function close_page(page){
        $('#menu a').removeClass('active').find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);
        Cufon.replace('#menu a', { fontFamily: 'Ubuntu', hover:true });
        location.hash='#';
        $(act).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'0'},700,'easeOutCirc', function(){
            $(act).css({display:'none'});
            act='';
            fl=true;
            $('#content').stop().animate({height:'668'})
        }); 
        return false;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I didnt do the effort to read all your code. It seems like you are doing a amateur homepage (initial css properties set via javascript instead of using a stylesheet, missing semicolons, global variables, etc.). 
For that purpose you could easily let the first link be clicked by javascript at pageload. 
This is a little dirty but it will work and it seems you don't care if its dirty or not.
 So put

```
$('#menu > li > a : first ').click();
```

somewhere in your $(window).load(function(){...}).